# тег input поле ввода

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня на странице есть поле ввода реализованное тегом input. Есть переменная которая хранит в себе какое-то значение. Как сделать так чтоб это значение всегда присутствовало в начале этого поля ввода и чтоб это значение нельзя было стереть?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myVar = "hohoho: ";
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
elem.value = myVar;

['change', 'keyup'].forEach(function(ev){
  elem.addEventListener(ev, function(){
    this.value = this.value.length <= myVar.length
      ? myVar
      : this.value.substr(myVar.lenght);
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Просто одно событие input используйте вместо этих циклов. Иначе можно стереть начальное слово вставкой из буфера например.